# How would you save/keep the separator for split() function on python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, split

I am starting to learn Python and this is my first day. I have read a book on learning Python and I found a built-in function called `split()`. I tried it out and worked, but I noticed that it did **not** include the separator in the list it made. Is there anyway I could save it? (I don't want to **manually add** the separator to the list.)

Here is my code:

```py
text = "hello!Hello!"

newtext = text.split("!")

for i in range(len(newtext)):
    print(newtext[i])
```

Output:

```
hello
Hello
```

Comment: Please update your question with your actual and expected output.

Comment: If you mean you want `[‘hello!’, ‘Hello!’]`, have a look into regex using the `re` library.  It’s also built in.

Comment: Additionally, you can simplify your loop to `for i in newtext`.

Comment: btw If you have seen `for i in range(len(newtext)):` in a book, then I suggest you are reading the wrong book.

Comment: @quamrana It was a few months ago so I believe I forgot. The book was Head First: Python.